# How to search in Django by giving condition

Tags: python, django

I have a table in db which look like this
[image: myRuletable]

I need to search by Rule No and store the search string which is **Epic="DevOps" AND Desc = "desc1"  variable** in a variable.
note: i gave example for Rule no 1. for all the rule i have to search and store that in a variable

Here's my model for Rule table:

```
class assignmentRule(models.Model): 
    Developer = models.ForeignKey(developer, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    Jira_Column = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    RelationalOperators= models.CharField(max_length=100)
    Jira_Value = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    LogicalOperator = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    Rule_No = models.CharField(max_length=30)
```

here my developer table:

```
class developer(models.Model):  
    Developer_Name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    Role = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    Level = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    Expertise = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    Availability_Hours = models.CharField(max_length=500)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.Developer_Name
```

Anyone guide me how to do that in django? and what to write in view to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty simple, juste unpack what you need :

```py
query_args = {}

rules = AssignmentRule.objects.filter(rule_no=1)

for rule in rules:
    query_args[rule.jira_column] = rule.jira_value

result = XXXXXXModel.objects.filter(**query_args)
```

Comment: in your code you are specifying the condition only for rule_no 1 but i want to make it dynamic , if it is Rule 2 also same for loop should apply

Comment: pretty simple instead of `rule_no=1` do `rule_no__in=[1,2,XXXXX]`